# Adding Custom Fields to WordPress Comment Forms?

Tags: customization, comments

What is the best way to add custom fields to a WordPress comment form?
(for example subject, image, etc...)

And how do I use the data entered afterwards...

Comment: Can you please review your question and Mike's answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi *@hannit cohen*:

This slideshow from [Beau Lebens](http://dentedreality.com.au/) should be able to show you how:

- [**Hooking into Comments**](http://www.slideshare.net/beaulebens/hooking-into-comments-5047868)

And this blog post from [Otto](http://ottodestruct.com/) should be able to show you more:

- [**WordPress 3.0 Theme Tip: The Comment Form**](http://ottopress.com/2010/wordpress-3-0-theme-tip-the-comment-form/)

Comment: after trying to use then, figured out they show how to addd the fiekds, but not how to get the entered data afterwards :-(

Comment: *@hannit cohen*: Can you post your code that you used that did work so we don't have to guess at what exactly you are doing? Thanks.

Comment: Is there a modern source on the web to this same exact process that worked back in 2010?

Answer (score 0):

My newly updated plugin **(version 2)** is available here 
http://www.solaceten.info/wp-extra-comment-fields-v2

Now fully automated and compliant with WP standards :-)

You can add extra comment fields automatically using the plugin, make them public or private, and make them mandatory or not.

Use radio, text fields or dropdowns! Lots of options :-)

Comment: please update your link (404)