# Add Comment Custom Field

Tags: comments, comment-meta

I searched a lot of thread regarding my problem, but unfortunately I found nothing works, and this my final option. I want to add some custom fields on my comment form. How can I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here you go: [Adding Custom Fields to WordPress Comment Forms?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1353/adding-custom-fields-to-wordpress-comment-forms)

And another awesome post on this: http://wpengineer.com/2214/adding-input-fields-to-the-comment-form/

Functions are available to add/update, delete comment meta, similar to post and user meta.

**Edit:**
Here's an example to give you a start (put the code into the `functions.php` or in a custom plugin):

Add the fields to comment form:

```
add_filter( 'comment_form_defaults', 'change_comment_form_defaults');
function change_comment_form_defaults( $default ) {
    $commenter = wp_get_current_commenter();
    $default[ 'fields' ][ 'email' ] .= '<p class="comment-form-author">' .
                                            '<label for="city">'. __('City') . '</label>
                                        <span class="required">*</span>
                                        <input id="city" name="city" size="30" type="text" /></p>';
    return $default;
}
```

4 functions to retrieve/add/update/delete comment meta:

```
get_comment_meta( $comment_id, $meta_key, $single = false );
add_comment_meta($comment_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $unique = false );
update_comment_meta($comment_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $unique = false );
delete_comment_meta( $comment_id, $meta_key, $single = false );
```

This is where you'd do the validations:

```
add_filter( 'preprocess_comment', 'verify_comment_meta_data' );
function verify_comment_meta_data( $commentdata ) {
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['city'] ) )
        wp_die( __( 'Error: please fill the required field (city).' ) );
    return $commentdata;
}
```

And save the comment meta:

```
add_action( 'comment_post', 'save_comment_meta_data' );
function save_comment_meta_data( $comment_id ) {
    add_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'city', $_POST[ 'city' ] );
}
```

Retrieve and display comment meta:

```
add_filter( 'get_comment_author_link', 'attach_city_to_author' );
function attach_city_to_author( $author ) {
    $city = get_comment_meta( get_comment_ID(), 'city', true );
    if ( $city )
        $author .= " ($city)";
    return $author;
}
```

(**Note**: All the code is from the [WPengineer](http://wpengineer.com/2214/adding-input-fields-to-the-comment-form/) link I posted above. There are more details and advanced usages in that post, please check them too! )

Answer (score 1):

This slideshow from Beau Lebens should be able to show you how:
[Hooking into Comments](http://www.slideshare.net/beaulebens/hooking-into-comments-5047868)

And this blog post from Otto should be able to show you more:
[WordPress 3.0 Theme Tip: The Comment Form](http://ottopress.com/2010/wordpress-3-0-theme-tip-the-comment-form/)

There is also a basic plugin available here called "Wordpress Plugin: Extra Comment Fields" (sorry can't post the link).

Comment: Links can get deleted. Please improve your answer with some of the content you found on the links. Best would be to add an example.

Comment: thanks for the answer buddy, it helps me too but id rather choose rutwick's answer. Thank you :)