# add field comment

Tags: comments, comment-form, comment-meta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add Comment Custom Field](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56775/add-comment-custom-field)

[Add Comment Custom Field](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56775/add-comment-custom-field/56913#56913)
I'm also interested with this, but where should I put those codes? help me guys..

Comment: You're best asking in the comments of the answer where the code should go

Comment: I made an update to the linked answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it inside your theme, use `functions.php`. Else make a new plugin with this code on it and install it.