# Saving value of a selection option in comment form as comment meta

Tags: plugin-development, custom-field, post-meta, comment-form

In a plugin that I am writing I need to let user choose an option from a dropdown list before they post a comment. I used the comment_form action and inserted a drop down into the comment form.

```
/**
 * Modify the comment to add our custom left and right dropdown
 */
function modify_comment_form($post_id) {
    echo "
    <label class='comment'>Choose your side:</label>
    <select id='tallytree_side' name='tallytree_side'>
        <option selected='selected' value='neutral'>Neutral Comment</option>
        <option value='left_answer'>" . $this->get_left_answer() . "</option>
        <option value='right_answer'>" . $this->get_right_answer() . "</option>
    </select>";
}
add_action('comment_form', 'modify_comment_form');
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

Now I just need to be able to save the value of this dropdown list when the comment is posted as a meta data of this particular comment. Note that this is a plugin and I dont want to modify core wordpress files as suggested in [a tutorial here](http://www.soapboxdave.com/2010/02/using-wordpress-comment-meta/). I found [a relevant discussions](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/adding-an-extra-field-to-the-comments?replies=18) on the wordpress forum but I still could not find the answer I was looking for.

How can I save the selected option value as a comment meta in wordpress database?

Do I need to use AJAX for this or can this be achieved by simply using an action or filter that I could use to retrieve the value of the dropdown menu?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add Comment Custom Field](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56775/add-comment-custom-field)

Comment: I dont think it is exact duplicate. But it did help me understand a bit more what I needed to do to process custom fields in the comment form. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function [`update_user_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta) for logged in users and the php function [`setcookie`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) for the visitors. Here is a start how to work with `update_user_meta`

You can run this function on submission of the form or by running it by AJAX, i would recommend you to run it with AJAX.

```
function wpse_update_user_commentform() {

    /**
     * Get values from the selected
     * Dropdown as tha variable $side
     * Change this to your dropdown name
    */

    $side = $_POST['dropdown'];

    $comment_id = get_comment_ID();

    // Update the comment meta "comment_side" to the selected value
    update_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'comment_side', $side );

}
```

Comment: Why do you want to add user meta data? We got a dedicated comments and comments meta table.

Comment: Thank you for your response. As I asked in the question I wanted to save the data as comment meta. Please edit your answer to save for comment meta instead of user and I will accept it.